# How could I change the placeholder of a text field based on the width?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport, responsive

Say I have a search field with `width: 50%;` of html.

html:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, , class: "search", placeholder: "Search for anything..." %>
```

css:

```
.search {width: 50%;}
```

When `.search` is wide enough, let's say wider than 200px, I want the placeholder text to be "Search for anything...". But when the width gets too small to contain the full text, let's say narrower than 200px, I want the placeholder text to be just "Search".

I can use viewports to change the CSS, but how can I make the placeholder text responsive?

Comment: I dont think that option is available. All you can do is prepare 2 inputs with value as " Search for anything..." and "Search". based on your viewports hide and show your inputs, and also do not forget to disable atleast one of them. else 2 inputs with same name will be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can have different textfields with different placeholder and show only the one you need.

Comment: So use CSS viewports to show and hide the multiple fields as appropriate?

Comment: Sure, otherwise you would have to use javascript to set the placeholder and it would be more complicated.

Comment: What js method could I use?

Comment: It's much more complicated, you'll have to put a listener to check if the size changes, then if the size changes you'll have to set the new placeholder. If you are using jquery then changing the placeholder would be something like this: $(".search").attr("placeholder", "Search for anything ...").focus().blur();